# How to calculate $f'(x)$ when the function has $ x^ {\gt 2}$?

Tags: calculus, functions

> I have this function:
> $$f(x) = |x^5 + 3x -1|$$
> I need to calculate $f'(0)$ ?

I am having difficulties because I don't know how to solve a function with $x^5$ !

I think this is a tricky question , and there is no need to know How to solve $x^5$ functions !

**Edit**

i found this answer but i am not sure How this, i will be happy to explanations:

f(x) is a combination for this tow functions:

`g(x) = x^5 + 3x -1`   & `w(x) = |x|`.

```
f'(0) = w'(-1)*g'(0) = -3
```

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dx} x^n = n\cdot x^{n-1}, n\in\mathbb N$$ But before that you should think about the absolute value, as $x\mapsto |x|$ is not differentiable everywhere.

Comment: For $n \neq 0$, we have the general rule $\frac{d}{dx}(x^n) = n x^{n - 1}$, but the difficult part of this problem is the absolute value sign.

Comment: thank you , i've edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x^5+3x-1$ is a continuous function which is negative at $x=0$, we can differentiate $f$ there using the result, valid in an open interval around $x=0$, that $f=1-3x-x^5$. The derivative is $-3-5x^4$, so $f'\left(0\right)=-3$.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i think this true, i've edit the question could you please have a look and tell how f'(0) = w'(-1)*g'(0)

Comment: If you draw the graph of $\left|x\right|$ you'll see that around any $x\neq 0$ it's a straight line, of slope $1$ for $x>0$ or $-1$ for $x<0$. In your notation, $w'(-1)=-1$. So your use of the chain rule gives the correct answer. (In case you're wondering, the derivative of $\left|x\right|$ is undefined at $x=0$, because the left-derivative is not equal to the right-derivative.)

Comment: thank you again, i think you are correct , but i am not sure that i understand well. could you please give me more clarification why f'(0) = w'(-1)*g'(0). setp by step. thanks

Comment: Since $f=w(g(x))$, the chain rule gives $\tfrac{df}{dx}=\tfrac{dw}{dg}\tfrac{dg}{dx}=w'(g(x))g'(x)$ so $f'(0)=w'(g(0))g'(0)$.